# React Redux : saving and displaying data

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to make a React app where I have a form and when submitted I want to show the data on the screen. I am also using redux. I am new to all that so I can't figure out **how to save the data to the store and then display it**.

If someone can tell me what I need to do. I think I should save the data from the form, pass it to the store but don't know how.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import * as actions from "../redux/actions";

export class AddAnimal extends Component {
  state = {
    animal: {
      name: "",
      animal: ""
    }
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <br />

        <input type="text" name="animal" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" className="btn" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    animals: state.animals
  };
};

const mapStateToDispatch = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      addAnimal: actions.addAnimal
    },
    dispatch
  );
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapStateToDispatch
)(AddAnimal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. you can locally save the form inputs data in a state Object inside the `AddAnimal` component such that it won't update redux state on every key change.

And on click of `onSubmit` you can dispatch an action (`addAnimal` which can be accessed by this.props.addAnimal) with form data as an argument. On dispatching it will call your reducer and save the data in the redux state.

As your AddAnimal component is listening on animals redux's state change. On updating redux state you can fetch newly updated data via props. (this.props.animals). But this will be only required if you want to show added data on UI inside the AddAnimal component.

Comment: Can you create a sandbox?

Comment: You can look at this link to get an idea - https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react/#implementing-other-components

Comment: can you give me link to sandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/oj7px08qy9 - you can look at this example. If you want you can edit this and implement your logic here by forking it

Comment: okay,here is my code in sandbox, please show me   https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-dew-nuqfx

Comment: I have updated your sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-kapitsa-mtjl9

Comment: If you are new to React/Redux then I would suggest going through the react documentation. Like how to handle input controls and manage its state.

Comment: thank you so much, and if I want to show it on the page not in the console?

Comment: You need to pass `animals` as a prop from the container component to the AddAnimal component. Then you can use that prop to display it on UI as per your requirement.

Comment: It is better to create a different view component that displays the list of animal.

`</>
     <AddAnimal onAnimalAdd={props.addAnimal} />
      <AnimalList animals={props.animals} />
</>`

Comment: i know it is too much, but can you make it in the sandbox

Comment: That depends on your UI requirements how to display the data on the UI. You need to code yourself. If you get stuck with anything I would be happy to help you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. You can consider accepting this as an answer.

Comment: i updated the sandbox, I want to display the data in Adopt.js  , https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-sound-g8ts5

Comment: You can just include your Animal view component in the animal container component and pass animals to it. 
`function AddAnimalContainer(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <AddAnimal onAnimalAdd={props.addAnimal} />
      <Animals animals={props.animals} />
    </div>
  );
}`

Comment: the data from the form is it saved in the store?

Comment: yeah, it is saved in the store. But it's up to you where to store the data. If you want the data to be stored at a global level then store it in the redux state such that any component can subscribe to that store.

Comment: can you give me your email so I can get in touch with you?

Comment: We can connect over here - https://www.linkedin.com/in/abhishekkumar001

Answer (score 0):

### Unnecessary mapStateToDispatch

in the component fix export to this:

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(AddAnimal);`

and you do not need `mapStateToDispatch`

and try to active the action with: `this.props.addAnimal();`